# How to change a value in a varable object list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that makes a variable object list but if I want to change one of the values for one of the keys I can't, can someone help me with this issue?

I'm using bootstrap and jquery/javascript to try to get it to work

```js
let keyholders = [{}];

function addPerson(){
   var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
   var addNameSelect = '';
   let id = keyholders.length;
    var newHolder = {
    [name]:{
        "id": id,
        "keys": {
          "garage": false,
          "frontdoor": false,
          "balcony": false,
        },
      },
    };
    keyholders.push(newHolder);
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="NAME" type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="addPerson()" type="button" id="personadd">ADD</button>
```

Ive tried to use:

```
var holder = document.getElementById('name').value;
keyholders.holder.keys.garage = true;
```

but my console says .holder is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write like this,

```
let index = keyholders.findIndex(item => Object.keys(item).includes(holder));
if(index > -1) {
    keyholders[index][holder].keys.garage = true;
 }
```

Because keyholders is an array and you should access by index and inside that index you should access using the holder variable.

Comment: `keyholders` is an array. The `holder` value is a key of an object within the array. As such, this will not work.

Comment: Yes I figured this just after answer. Updated. Thanks for mentioning :)

Comment: i've implemented this in my code and it works fantasticly thanx for the help

Comment: If this solves your problem don't forget to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is because there is no `holder` property in the object. You need to access the object using array notation so that the *value* of `holder` is used as the key, not the literal work 'holder':

```
keyholders[holder]keys.garage = true;
```

However this raises a second issue due to the use of an array of objects - the `holder` key is not in the array, but the child object. As such without knowing the index of the object to find within you cannot retrieve the holder - and if you knew the index anyway, you wouldn't need to use `holder` at all.

As such it makes far more sense to just use a single object whose properties match the values entered in to the  `#name` box. Try this:

```js
let keyholders = {};

function addPerson() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var addNameSelect = '';
  let id = keyholders.length;

  keyholders[name] = {
    "id": id,
    "keys": {
      "garage": false,
      "frontdoor": false,
      "balcony": false,
    }
  };
  console.log('added');
}

document.querySelector('.set').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
  keyholders[name].keys.garage = true;
  console.log(keyholders);
});
```

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="NAME" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="foo">
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="addPerson()" type="button" id="personadd">ADD</button>

<button class="set">Set garage keys = true</button>
```